# Can't find spring integration aws schema location online

Tags: spring, xsd, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I can't find

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws.xsd

under

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/

Any help?

Comment: You should add a few more things to your question like - What all you have tried, What confused you or what stopped you from finding further etc. When someone sees incomplete question, they down-vote it. Happy coding!

Comment: I agree, but I thought it was enough context! Developer should know that why a developer need the xml schema! (XSD)?

Comment: Close to 20 million developers are there in the world, only 8 million are java professionals and I am sure lot of them may not have used XSD which goes as old as 2001 and that it stands for Xml Schema Definition. Please give the world some time to keep up, eh!

Comment: @nitinr708 : You are right, but that's why stackoverflow provides tag mechanism, if developer is not aware about the XSD and Spring(or java), then why should they look this question at all? I tagged this question properly!

Comment: perhaps it was unlucky a shooter stopped by your post! with his vote gun not reading the tag name plate ;) BEWARE OF VOTE HUNTERS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't care about that these days. The normal IDEs are able to resolve XSD against classpath, reading the content of the jars you provide for your project.

That schema is located here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/aws/config